# Is it right Store dependency kernel in app onstart as static variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject

I add DI to wpf application by using Ninject framework. 
Is it appropriate to store kernel as static member of App class, 
or I'd rather delete it from App class and create instance anytime I need to use it in code of windows right before using(IUnitOfWork unit = new ... ) block?

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    internal static StandardKernel kernel;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Calling the kernel in different windows:

```
using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = App.kernel.Get<IUnitOfWork>())
        {
            comboFloors.ItemsSource = unitOfWork.Buildings.GetLivingFloors();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it appropriate to store kernel as static member of App class, or I'd rather delete it from App class and create instance anytime I need to use it in code of windows

You should typically only have one instance of the `Kernel` class during the lifetime of an an application. `Kernel` instances are safe to be used over threads and are optimized for reuse. Creating them for each request or window can cause a major overhead (in menory and performance).

Where to store this instance is a different story. You typically want to prevent calling directly from application code. You only want to use it inside your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). In case only the App class itself can get a hold of the `Kernel` and resolve services from it, it seems perfectly fine to me.